# Merge nested dict to root jq

Tags: jq

I am trying to create something like table with instance ID and theirs tags and another details, and that step where i got stuck it's move EC2 tags that placed in nested Array as Dict objects. Here is already transormed "Tags" dict, just need to put it together with another data.

```
{
  "Id": "i-0e27418e091ea97a7",
  "Name": "php"
}
{
  "Id": "i-0b0a0cb6223701cb5",
  "Name": "Logics-SF-Migration",
  "q": "ngix"
}
```

Above desired result, down is source json.

```
{
  "Id": "i-0e27418e091ea97a7",
  "Tags": {
    "Name": "php"
  }
}
{
  "Id": "i-0b0a0cb6223701cb5",
  "Tags": {
    "Name": "Main,
    "q": "ngix"
  }
}
```

Comment: The line `"Name": "Main` is missing a closing double quote

Comment: I am sorry, just were editing it by hands

Comment: `"Name": "Main"` (regardless of the missing quotes) is also missing entirely in the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the root path with the `.Tags` and delete it afterwards. You could use a temporary variable as well i.e. `.Tags as $v | del(.Tags) | . + $v`

```
jq '. + .Tags | del(.Tags)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be

```sh
jq 'del(.Tags) + .Tags'
```

```json
{
  "Id": "i-0e27418e091ea97a7",
  "Name": "php"
}
{
  "Id": "i-0b0a0cb6223701cb5",
  "Name": "Main",
  "q": "ngix"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PfGihF44GT)

The major difference to other solutions like `. + .Tags | del(.Tags)` is that this deletes from the unaltered source, not the populated result, which does affect content in `.Tags.Tags`, if present. Example:

```json
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Tags": {
    "Name": "What about nested Tags?",
    "Tags": "Should they be deleted?"
  }
}
```

```sh
jq '(          . + .Tags | del(.Tags) ),
    ( del(.Tags) + .Tags              )'
```

```json
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Name": "What about nested Tags?"
}
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Name": "What about nested Tags?",
  "Tags": "Should they be deleted?"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Nb0NE1h7aN)